# Why can I get the process of my while condition with biginteger variable

Tags: java

I want to make my while loop work when the condition is not equal to one. 
I want to make 
while (biginteger a is not one), but in my code it is not working

```
while (hasil.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1)) == 0) {
    hasil = d.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(b)).remainder(BigInteger.valueOf(m));

    out.println(d + " x " + b + "mod " + m + "=" + hasil);

    d = d.add(BigInteger.ONE);            
}
```

Comment: Your while condition is testing that your variable _is_ equal to 1.

Comment: 0 is equal, -1 less, 1 greater, hence `!= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (hasil.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1)) == 0)
```

The above snippet is equivalent to the following:

```
while (BigInteger.ONE.equals(hasil))  // hasil == 1
```

To check if `hasil` is **not** equal to `BigInteger.ONE`, you must negate the condition:

```
while (!BigInteger.ONE.equals(hasil)) // hasil != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the condition

```
while (hasil.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1)) != 0)
```

As you are looking for the value not to be equal to one, as mentioned by  @khelwood

Answer (score 0):

The logic inside the `while` condition is wrong, and tricky enough that it wasn't easy to spot. Instead of doing a single combined statement in the `while` condition, you could check something in the statement body, and use `break` to exit the loop.

Here's an example which uses a few statements to make it clear what the comparison is doing, and clear when the loop will exit.

```
while (true) {

    // do other things

    int result = hasil.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    boolean valuesAreEqual = (result == 0);
    if (valuesAreEqual) {
        break;
    }
}
```